# Погрешность std::chrono::steady_clock

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо каждый час выполнять какие то действия. Создаю что то типа таймера с помощью `std::chrono::steady_clock`, в `while` проверяю или пришло время выполнять действия. Судя по логам за каждый час набегает смещение вызова этих действий, а за 6 часов смещение становится больше 1 секунды. От куда берется это смещение? Разве `std::chrono::steady_clock` не подходит для такой задачи?

```
std::chrono::milliseconds PeriodCall(1000 * 60 * 60);
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point TimeNextCall; // Время следующей сработки таймера 

while (true)
{

    std::chrono::milliseconds time_delta = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(TimeNextCall - std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
    if (time_delta.count() <= 0)
    {
        TimeNextCall += PeriodCall;
        /*
        ...Выполняем действия
        */

    }

    Sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

жаль, что нет тега [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) у этого вопроса. Собственно, если `steady_clock()` стрейснуть под линукс, то сразу будет виден ответ — используется `clock_gettime()` с `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, а не `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`. Если тестеры наловчились сдвигать время при помощи NTP, `то steady_clock()` становится источником проблем.  Думаю, что и под другими операционными системами похожая ситуация.

Comment: Linux не используется, это видно по коду.